# SignalR is not receiving events every time

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm building poker game on ASP.NET + React and using signalR for real-time communication.
It works fine most of the time.
But sometimes on client side, I can't receive events from the server-side so from that moment, not synchronizing with other players.
After refreshing, it works again.
I can't find what's the problem and when it is not receiving.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const startConnection = async () => {
      let newConnection = await MainV2.startConnectionWithUserIdentity(user.Id);
      LogRocket.log("Connected to SignalR", newConnection.connectionId);
      /* newConnection.onclose(() => {
        newConnection.start();
      }); */
      setConnection(newConnection);
    };

    startConnection();
  }, [user]);
```

MainV2.startConnectionWithUserIdentity function is like

```
  const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(GetFullURL(`GameClass?UserIdentity=${UniqueId}`))
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

  if (connection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected) return;

  await connection.start();
```

This is the code that connect to the hub and below is the code that I attached event to the connection.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (connection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected) {
//.....

      connection.on("OtherPlayerDisconnected", (UserId, UserName) => {
        OtherPlayerDisconnected(UserId, UserName);
      });

      connection.on("ReceiveHashV1", () => {
        SendRequest({
          url: "GameV2/_GetGameHash",
          method: "post",
          data: { GameCode },
        }).then((result) => {
          LogRocket.log("Received GameHash on Game: " + GameCode, {
            GameHash: result.data,
          });

          setGameHash(result.data);
        });
      });

      setConnection(connection);
    }

    return () => {
      if (connection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected) {
        connection.off("ReceiveHashV1");
        connection.off("OtherPlayerDisconnected");
        connection.off("ReceiveEndHandSummary");
        connection.off("ReceiveEndGameSummary");
        connection.off("ReceiveCancelHandNotification");
        connection.off("RemovedNotification");
        connection.off("ReceiveMessage");

        setConnection(connection);
      }
    };
  }, [
    connection.connectionId,
  ]);
```

I can't find where it is not receiving events so can't do anything.

```
public class GameClass : Hub
    {
        public static List<string> ConnectionIds = new List<string>();
        public static bool IsBusy = false;
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        private readonly DBCardGameContext _dbCardGameContext;
        public GameClass(DBCardGameContext dbCardGameContext)
        {
            _dbCardGameContext = dbCardGameContext;
        }

        /*
            Send "ReceiveMessage" to all clients.
        */
        public int SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsBusy == false)
                {
                    IsBusy = true;
                    var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
                    var val2 = Context.User;
                    var val3 = Clients.Caller;

                    ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

                    Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        /*
        Send "ReciveNotification" to all Clients.
        @param
        gamecode: GameCode that will receive notfication.
        playerid: PlayerId that send notficiation.
        notificationmessage: message
        */
        public async Task SendNotification(string gamecode, string playerid, string notificationmessage)
        {
            var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
            var val2 = Context.User;
            var val3 = Clients.Caller;

            // ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", gamecode, playerid, notificationmessage);
        }

        public async Task GameLog(string GameCode, string ActionName, string PlayerUniqueId, string PlayerName)
        {

        }

        /*
         SendRemoveNotification
         */
        public async Task SendRemoveNotification(string GameCode, string UserId)
        {
            var player = await _dbCardGameContext.Player.Where(x => x.GameCode == GameCode && x.PlayerUniqueId == UserId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
            await Clients.Client(player.SignalRconnectionId).SendAsync("RemovedNotification");
        }

        /*
        Send "ReceiveEndGameSummary"
        @param
        gamecode: GameCode that send notification
        */
        public async Task SendEndGameSummary(string gamecode)
        {
            var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
            var val2 = Context.User;
            var val3 = Clients.Caller;

            // ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveEndGameSummary", gamecode);
        }

        /*
        Send "ReceiveEndHandSummary"
        @param
        gamecode: GameCode that send notification
        */
        public async Task SendEndHandSummary(string gamecode)
        {
            var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
            var val2 = Context.User;
            var val3 = Clients.Caller;

            // ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveEndHandSummary", gamecode);
        }

        //same as SendMessage
        public async Task SendMessage2(string user, string message, string test)
        {
            var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
            var val2 = Context.User;
            var val3 = Clients.Caller;

            ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonData = js.Serialize(ConnectionIds); // {"Name":"C-

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        //same as SendMessage    
        public async Task ReceiveOnLoad(string user, string message)
        {
            var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
            var val2 = Context.User;
            var val3 = Clients.Caller;

            // string val1 = "";
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonData = js.Serialize(ConnectionIds); // {"Name":"C-

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, jsonData);
        }

        // when you connect to GameClass Hub, this function invoked.
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            HttpContext httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();

            //Get PlayerUniqueId of connecting user
            /*var customQuerystring = httpContext.Request.QueryString.Value.Split("&").FirstOrDefault().Split("=").LastOrDefault();

            if (customQuerystring != null)
            {
                //If player already added to Database, just change player's Modified time and isConnected = true, SignalRconnectionId as new connectionId.
                var player = _dbCardGameContext.Player.Where(x => x.PlayerUniqueId == customQuerystring).FirstOrDefault();
                if (player != null)
                {
                    player.LastActionTime = DateTime.Now;
                    player.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                    player.SignalRconnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
                    player.IsConnected = true;
                    _dbCardGameContext.SaveChanges();
                }

                //If not exist, Add new player
                else
                {
                    _dbCardGameContext.Player.Add(new Player() { Created = DateTime.Now, IsConnected = true, LastActionTime = DateTime.Now, PlayerUniqueId = customQuerystring, SignalRconnectionId = Context.ConnectionId });
                    _dbCardGameContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }*/
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        //when you close connection, this function invokes.
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId);
            try
            {
                //Get disconnectedplayer
                var disconnectedplayer = _dbCardGameContext.Player.Where(x => x.SignalRconnectionId == Context.ConnectionId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (disconnectedplayer != null)
                {
                    //If disconnectedplayer currently join game and active, set him deactive.
                    if (disconnectedplayer.GameCode != "" && disconnectedplayer.GameCode != null)
                    {
                        disconnectedplayer.IsConnected = false;
                        disconnectedplayer.IsActive = false;
                        disconnectedplayer.IsCurrent = false;
                        disconnectedplayer.IsDealer = false;
                        disconnectedplayer.IsFolded = false;

                        _dbCardGameContext.SaveChanges();

                        //all other players in the same game
                        var allrelatedplayers = _dbCardGameContext.Player.Where(x => x.GameCode == disconnectedplayer.GameCode && x.SignalRconnectionId != Context.ConnectionId).ToList();
                        foreach (var ar in allrelatedplayers)
                        {
                            //Send "OtherPlayerDisconnected" msg.
                            Clients.Client(ar.SignalRconnectionId).SendAsync("OtherPlayerDisconnected", disconnectedplayer.PlayerUniqueId, disconnectedplayer.UserName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            Task tsk = new Task(() =>
            {

            });

            return tsk;
        }
    }
```

This is the main code.

```
//send ReceiveHashV1 Message to all of members.
                            foreach (var p in players)
                            {
                                if (p.PlayerUniqueId != userid)
                                {
                                    _HubContext.Clients.Client(p.SignalRconnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveHashV1", "100");
                                }
                            }
```

```
connection.on("ReceiveHashV1", () => {
        SendRequest({
          url: "GameV2/_GetGameHash",
          method: "post",
          data: { GameCode },
        }).then((result) => {
          LogRocket.log("Received GameHash on Game: " + GameCode, {
            GameHash: result.data,
          });

          setGameHash(result.data);
        });
      });
```

Comment: Asp.net signalr or asp.net core signalr ? And you also need to share the hub class.

Comment: It's asp.net core

Comment: added hub class.

Comment: Could you  try to  change this `public int SendMessage(string user, string message)` method to async, and check it works or not ?

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Try it, and the next action will be enable the logs for asp.net core signalr server and client.

Comment: I'm not sure when it's not receving.
Really rare case but I have to be 100% sure about that.

Comment: should I change all functions to async?

Comment: Yes, it is recommand.

Comment: Those function is not called actually.

Comment: I've add the code that is not working at the end.

Comment: The reason why SendMessage not been invoked is you need to use ` connection.invoke()` to call backend method.

Comment: And if the method inside the Hub class want to send message to client, we can use `Clients.All.SendAsync` to call it, then we can use `connection.on`  to receive the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue related to below method.

```
    public int SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsBusy == false)
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
                var val2 = Context.User;
                var val3 = Clients.Caller;

                ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

                Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

My suggestion is you can try to remove all the conditions inside this method, like below, to check it works or not.

```
    public async Task  SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        var val1 = Context.ConnectionId;
        var val2 = Context.User;
        var val3 = Clients.Caller;

        ConnectionIds.Add(user + "===" + message);

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
```